# Regex Expression to extract Address Street from a string

Tags: python, regex

Given the sample texts, I want to extract Address Street (text between asterisk).
Using the below Regex Expression, I'm able to extract Address Street for most of the sentences but mainly failing for text4 & text5.

```
regex = r"(^[0-9]+[\s\-0-9,A-Za-z]+)"
text1 = *9635 E COUNTY ROAD, 1000 N*.
text2 = *8032 LIBERTY RD S*.
text3 = *2915 PENNSYLVANIA AVENUE*  40 Other income (loss) 15 Alternative minimum tax (AMT) ilems
A 2,321
text4 = *2241 Western Ave*. 10 Other income loss 15 — Altemative minimum tax AMT itams
text5 = *450 7TH STREET, APT 2-M*
text6 = *9635 East County Road 1000 North*

My code---
for k,v in val.items():
 if k == "Shareholder Address Street":
   text = " ".join(v)
   pattern1 = r"(^[0-9]+[\s\-0-9,A-Za-z]+)"
   addressRegex = re.compile(pattern1)
   match = addressRegex.search(text)
   if match is not None:
      delta = []
      delta.append("".join(match.group(0)))
      val[k] = delta
```

Can anyone please suggest the change in the above regex as it is working fine for most of the documents?

Comment: You need to show us _all_ the various forms of address which might be appearing in your text.  Otherwise, any answer given below might immediately be rendered invalid when you reveal some edge case.

Comment: Currently, I'm getting these 6 different forms of address.

Comment: @RevolverRakk Can you share the code that you are using?

Comment: @ The fourth bird, I've shared my code snippet, where I'm applying Regex to extract the Address street and storing in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```py
^\d+(?:[ \t][\w,-]+)*
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/OONAEX/1)

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ \t]                    any character of: ' ', '\t' (tab)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w,-]+                  any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), ',', '-' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The Regex is working fine in the online tester but is it failing for text3 i.e "2915 PENNSYLVANIA AVENUE  40 Other income (loss) ....." when tested in my IDE & returning the whole string instead of "2915 PENNSYLVANIA AVENUE"

Comment: @RevolverRakk Sorry, I cannot reproduce, see https://regex101.com/r/OONAEX/2

Comment: Thanks for ur guidance, I will try to make some changes as per my requirement.